# What is the purpose of "return methodA() || methodB()" in Java

Tags: java, return, conditional-statements

I found this code snippet in a program I'm looking at, can someone explain what's going on here?

```
return methodA() || methodB();
```

methodA and methodB eventually return booleans. Is this some kind of exception protection or will this statement always return methodA()?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It calls `methodA` and checks the result. If true, it returns true immediately. Otherwise, it calls `methodB` and returns that.

Anyway, this is known as a short circuiting operator. I'd recommend learning a bit more about Java's operators, because you'll probably see stuff like this a lot.

If the short circuiting behavior was not desired, they could have used

```
return methodA() | methodB();
```

Which will call both methods, perform a bitwise or on the results (which is equivalent to logical or on booleans) and return the result.

Comment: Thanks, very informative answer and this one is surprisingly hard to google for

Answer (score 3):

It means that if `methodA` returns `true` then use that as the return value, otherwise use the return value of `methodB`. A sort of cascadingly evaluated return value.

Answer (score 0):

It is shortened form of following:

```
boolean a = methodA();
boolean b = methodB();

if(a) {
    return true;
}
else if(b) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

If `methodA()` returns true then methodB() will not be called and true will be returned. If `MethodA()` returns false, then `methodB()` will be called an its value will be returned back.

Comment: There's a semantic difference between this code and the code in the OP; this code always calls `methodB`.

Comment: Refer the text below my sample code. It is already mentioned. I was trying to explain with clear variables and easy readability.